# Algebra shortcut quick method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Its a revised-Gre question**
it is given that

$$1000 = a^2 b$$ 
where a and b could be any number.  It is possible to find different set of answers for the equation given, but how can I  know the sets for **a** and **b** that will satisfy the question.

now if I  am asked to  find that **which option will  be  for** $a+b$?

1. $45$
2. 252
3. 1000

Comment: $a=2$, $b=250$?

Comment: Also $a=5$ and $b=40$

Comment: There aren't a lot of possibilities anyway : (1,1000) , (2,250),(5,40),(10,10) The answers are both $1$ and $2$

Comment: Is it actually part of the question that $a$ and $b$ must be integers, if not, then any sum is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1000=2^3 \cdot 5^3$

and we have

$a=1$ and $b=1000$
$a=2$ and $b=2\cdot 5^3=250$
$a=5$ and $b=2^3\cdot 5=40$
$a=2\cdot5=10$ and $b=2\cdot 5=10$

Answer (score 2):

$$1000=2^35^3.$$ As $a^2$ is a perfect square, it must be one of

$$1,2^2=4,5^2=25,2^25^2=10^2=100.$$

The corresponding $a+b$ are

$$1001,252,45,20.$$